# Matchit fails when using it with exact method on large categorical variable

Tags: r, propensity-score-matching

I am using the matchit command from the [same name package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=MatchIt) to try to apply matching to a research purpose. I need to match exactly on one variable and estimate propensity scores with remaining variables. For this purpose, I use:

```
library(MatchIt)

m.out <- matchit(formula = treatment ~ X1 + X2 + ... + X13,
 exact = ~ X14,
 method = "glm",
 data = mydata)
```

But I get the following error message:

> error in rbind(125859L, 145779L, integer(0), 143419L, 195729L,
> integer(0),:  number of columns of matrices must match

and thus the function returns nothing. I guess the issue is because X14 is a very large categorical variables (it has near to 1000 different levels) and I cannot reduce its dimensionality without altering its meaningfulness.

I tried to condition on another variable and just ignore X14 with

```
m.out <- matchit(formula = treatment ~ X1 + X2 + ... + X12,
 exact = ~ X13,
 method = "glm",
 data = mydata)
```

with X13 being a lower dimensional factor variable and it works. I was wondering whether anyone else faced this kind of issue at some point and how I could solve it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This sounds like a bug. In the future, please report bugs to the `MatchIt` [issues page](https://github.com/kosukeimai/MatchIt/issues). I have made some changes to fix these errors and the bug may already be fixed in the development version, which you can install using `remotes::install_github("ngreifer/MatchIt")`

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your time @Noah.  I will try as soon as possible to install this version.

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks again for your reply. I confirm the patch works well!

Comment: The bug should be fixed in the CRAN version of `MatchIt` now.